# How to change the selection highlight colour of text box in VB6/VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, vb6

How can I change the selection highlight colour of a text box in VB6 and VB.NET. By default selection highlight colour is Blue, but I want to change it to my desired colour without using a custom control.

Comment: That is based on the *user's* desired color scheme/theme in use on *their*  system.  You have no way of knowing if your choice will look good or even show up.

Comment: Create your own control...

Comment: I am not able to find the API which can change the selection highlight colour of existing VB text box control.

Comment: You can look into [Visual State Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I think that creating your own control might be an easier solution...

Comment: Ok! But creating a control will take a long time! I just want to change the highlight colour. Any sample code to change the highlight colour will do.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a global method (in .bas file) defining with your customize properties for text box and call this method on Form_Load() event.

```
Public Sub InitializedFormElement(frmRunning as Form)
  Dim ctrl
  For Each ctrl In frmRunning
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
       Case "TextBox"
          ctrl.Appearance = 0
          ctrl.Height = ctrl.Height-30
          ctrl.BackColor = vbBlue
     End Select
   Next
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
on error Resume Next
  Call InitializedFormElement (Me)
End Sub
```

you can replace vbBlue color with you desired color.

for color code you can help from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ys84h69%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to change the colour of the text selection (background) not the BackColor of the TextBox.

Comment: It is actually windows property. I think by using custom control you cannot change text highlighted color. But if you change window's color and appearance then highlighted color will be changed automatically in everywhere. Please follow the link to change windows color and appearance properties - https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/windows-7-and-8-changing-colours/

Comment: I have seen the link, but I think there is a way to do it by subclassing and without changing the system colour/appearance.